# DataTable show Ajax error while return Json in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

The model works well until I store Date datatype in my SQL Server
When I try return Json using `ToListAsync()`, it shows ajax error.
This is the Prog Models

```
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Module { get; set; }

    public string Product { get; set; }

    public string Segment { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

This is the function in Controller. `Bookscontroller` is the controller for Prog Model. I just didn't change the name.

```
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    [BindProperty]
    public Prog Prog { get; set; }

    public BooksController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    #region API Calls
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        return Json(new { data = await _db.Progs.ToListAsync() });
    }
```

This is the jquery in javascript using `DataTable`.

```
 dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/books/getall/",
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": "json"
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "name",
            "render": function (data) {
                return `<div class="text-left">
                        <a  href=""  style='cursor:pointer; width:80px;'>
                           ${data}
                        </a>
                        
                        </div>`;
            },"width": "20%"
        },
        { "data": "module", "width": "15%" },
        { "data": "product", "width": "15%" },
        { "data": "segment", "width": "15%" },
        { "data": "date", "width": "20%" },
```

Error shown in browser
[image: Error shown in browser]

> DataTables warning: table id=DT_load - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Inspection in browser
[image: Inspection in browser]

I try to console the url 'books/getall'
This is what i saw in my browser console.

Console in browser
[image: Console in browser]

What is the proper way to get Date datatype from SQL and turn into JSON format? The error occur after there is a value in Date datatype of my SQL server.

I double check and I realize it is because there are null value in my DateTime column. After removing null, the error no more.

Comment: Firstly,`"it shows ajax error."` what error you are getting, please include the error screenshot if possible. In addition, could you please share the detailts of `_db.Progs.`

Comment: @cmhack it clearly shows Internal Server Error (HTTP 500) which means that your .NET API is not returning valid json. Please try running the end point manually in your local chrome browser and share the output returned (might be xml as you are requesting via browser but we'll get a faint idea on the error as the error seems to be from server side).

Comment: i think I have some issue to get date datetype from SQL to my MVC model. somehow it does not turn to valid json format to DataTable.

Comment: The error occurs because there are null data inside DateTime column!!

Comment: Yes, if your data is `not nullable` then also need to consider that. However, in that case you could allow `datetime` as nullable.

Comment: How to allow datetime to be nullable? @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: You can do it either in database or in your class as well. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DataTable show Ajax error while return Json in .NET MVC

First of all, you should check if in your browser log if you got the respose as expected. I think, your backend code looks alright. However, your `jQuery` snippet for getting `json` for `datatable` doesn't seems correct. You could follow below steps:

**View: JQuery Datatable**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "BindDataTableFromJson";
}


<table id="bindDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Module</td>
            <td>Product</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

</table>
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/StackOverFlow/GetProg",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#bindDataTable').DataTable({
                        data: response,
                        columns: [
                            { data: 'bookId' },
                            { data: 'name' },
                            { data: 'module' },
                            { data: 'product' }

                        ]
                    });

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** Point to remember, while define your `column property` in `datatable` for example `bookId`, `name` must be in `lowercase` otherwise table will not traced the data accordingly. Furthermore, backend data should be same, case doesn't matter for that.

**Model:**

```
public class Prog
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Module { get; set; }

        public string Product { get; set; }

        public string Segment { get; set; }
        
        public DateTime Date{ get; set; }

       
    }
```

**Note:** Entity Model should have `primary-key` for instance `BookId`.

**Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetProg()
        {
            var listProg = _context.Progs.ToArray();
            return Json(listProg);
        }
```

**Note:** This controller will fetch the data. You can use `ToListAsync` that will work without issue as well.

**Controller**

public IActionResult ViewProg()
{
return View();
}

**Note:** This controller will load the view

**Output:**

[image]

**Example with datetime**

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to make DateTime as Nullable then you can do that in database like below:

[image]

Besides, In Entity Model, we can deifne a property as nullable by putting `?` in it. Like below:

```
 public DateTime? Date{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi Farid, thanks for the answer. I suspect the issue happened due to DateTime datatype. It works well until Datetime Date is added into my Model. Can shed some lights on this. Because SQL store Date but not DateTime.

Comment: Not at all, `datetime` and any data type doesn't has the issue with. Make sure your `Jquery` code are correct. See my example and just plug and play. In addition, check the update screnshoot as well.